# With how many ways can we put $2t+1$ similar balls in $3$ distinct boxes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

With how many ways can we put $2t+1$ similar balls in $3$ distinct boxes,so that each couple of boxes contains more balls that the third one.

I thought that these relations should stand:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3=2t+1$$
$$x_1+x_2 > x_3$$
$$x_1+x_3 > x_2$$
$$x_2+x_3 > x_1$$

So,can we do it like that:

From the inequalities:
$$ x_1+x_2-x_3>0 $$
$$ x_1+x_3-x_2>0 $$
$$ x_2+x_3-x_1>0 $$

we get,by adding, $ x_1,x_2,x_3>0 $..

So,

$$ y_i=x_i-1 \geq 0, i \in \{1,2,3 \} $$

Then $\displaystyle{  y_1+y_2+y_3+3=2t+1 \Rightarrow y_1+y_2+y_3=2t-2 }$

So,there are  $\displaystyle{ \binom{3+2t-1-1}{2}=\binom{2t}{2} } $ different ways.

?? Or can't this way be used?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and yes, of course you have to use them simultaneously. All three have to be satisfied, because it says *each* couple of boxes contains more balls than the third.

Comment: you could first assume $x_3$ is the largest one, then all you need to check is that $x_3 < t + 1$.

Comment: @M.Vinay Ok..but how can I do this????

Comment: @mm-aops and how could I continue then?

Answer (score 0):

The criteria given is simply saying that each box can have no more
that $t$ balls.

Let $S$ be the set of all arrangements of $2t+1$ balls in $3$
boxes.

The cardinality of this set uses the usual "stars and bars"
argument. Here we need the number of ways to arrange $2t+1$ balls
(stars) and $2$ box dividers (bars).

Thus, $\vert S\vert = \binom{2t+3}{2}$.

Let $S_i, i = 1,2,3,$ be the set of arrangements in $S$ where box
$i$ has at least $t+1$ balls.

For the cardinality of $S_i$ we need the number of ways to arrange
$\left(2t+1\right) - \left(t+1\right) = t$ balls and $2$ bars, since
there must be at least $t+1$ balls in box $i$.

Thus $\vert S_i \vert = \binom{t+2}{2}$.

Now seek the cardinality of set $\left( S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3
\right)^c$, where the complement is with respect to $S$.

Using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vert \left( S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \right)^c \vert &=& \vert S \vert - \vert S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \vert \\
&=& \vert S \vert - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{3}{\vert S_i \vert} -
\sum_{i<j}^{3}{\vert S_i \cap S_j \vert} + \vert S_1 \cap S_2 \cap
S_3 \vert \right) \\
&=& \binom{2t+3}{2} - 3 \binom{t+2}{2} \\
&&\qquad\mbox{since $S_i \cap
S_j$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3$ are empty sets} \\
&=& \left(2t+3\right)\left(t+1\right) -
3\left(t+2\right)\left(t+1\right)/2 \\
&=& 2t^2+5t+3 - \dfrac{3}{2}\left(t^2+3t+2\right) \\
&=& \left(t^2+t\right)/2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Mick A From the relations:
$$x_1+x_2-x_3 >0$$
$$x_1+x_3-x_2 >0$$
$$x_2+x_3 -x_1>0$$

don't we get that : $$x_1,x_2,x_3>0$$ ?
So,why isn't it like that: $$\binom{3+2t}{2}$$ ?

Comment: The set I called $S$ is ALL the arrangements of $2t+1$ balls in $3$ boxes without restriction. I use it to then subtract from it the arrangement that breaks those rules. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I edited my first post..Could you explain me if the exercise could also be done with this way?? I don't get the same result as yours :/

Comment: Verify your answer by setting $t=1$ (answer should be $1$), then $t=2$ (answer should be $3$).

Comment: So, the formula that I have found is wrong :( So,have I done something wrong at the calculations or is the way that I used wrong,for solving such type of problems??

Answer (score 0):

Another more straightforward method:

Given that all $3$ boxes can have no more than $t$ balls and must
have at least one due to the given restrictions, we simply sum up
the options.

If box $1$ has $i$ balls, i = 1,2, ... t, then box $2$ has from
$t-i+1$ to $t$ balls, leaving the remainder to box $3$. That is,
when box $1$ has $i$ balls, there are $t - \left(t-i+1\right)+1 = i$
options. E.g. When $i=1$, the only option is box $2$ has $t$ balls and so does box $3$.

Summing, we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
Ans &=& \sum_{i=1}^{t}{i} \\
&=& \left(t^2+t\right)/2
\end{eqnarray*}

Same answer as above but simpler.

Comment: Does this satisfy the fact that each couple of boxes should have more balls than the third one? :/

Comment: Yes, by looking at the limits I put on the sum and the number of options for each term in the sum. Box $1$ limited from $1$ to $t$, Box 2: any number from $t-I+1$ to $t$ is between $1$ and $t$. Box 3 is similarly restricted.